# How to use LINQ to sort custom items by using StartWith

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code. which is based on using a temp container to select specific items and then add them at the end of the list.

```
 var allRoles = roles.Table
      .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new FirmRole
      {
          Code = p.Field<string>("RoleName"),
          Name = p.Field<string>("RoleName")
      })ToList();

        var formRoles = allRoles.Where(p => p.Code.StartsWith("f")).ToList();
        var otherRoles = allRoles.Except(formRoles).ToList();

        otherRoles.AddRange(formRoles);
```

Would it be a better way to shorten this code and get rid of the temp list?

Something like

```
 var allRoles = roles.Table
      .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new FirmRole
      {
          Code = p.Field<string>("RoleName"),
          Name = p.Field<string>("RoleName")
      }).OrderBy(x=>x.Code.StartsWith("f")).ThenBy(a=>a);
```

Comment: Does your `FirmRole` override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`? Otherwise it won't work at all since `Distinct` only compares references by default. Also, the `ToList()` before the `OrderBy` is inefficient and unnecessary. You don't need a new list to be able to use `OrderBy`. If you need a list as final result do that as last.

Comment: No I doesn't override those methods. I actually do not need to Distinct. I can get rid of it. Would it work without Distinct or I would still need to override those methods?

Comment: `Except` also needs `Equals+GetHashCode` to work.

Comment: Except works with no issue without Equals+GetHashCode

Answer (score 1):

On `IEnumerable<T>` (as is in this case) you are right, because `OrderBy` is a stable sorting (see [Enumerable.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): *This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved.*, so for elements with the same key, their previous ordering is maintained. On `IQueryable<T>` this isn't guaranteed.

```
var allRoles = roles.Table
    .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new FirmRole
    {
        Code = p.Field<string>("RoleName"),
        Name = p.Field<string>("RoleName")
    }).Distinct()
      .OrderBy(x => x.Item.Code.StartsWith("f")) 
      .ToList();
```

Note that you don't need a secondary ordering, because `OrderBy` is, as I've said, stable.

Speedwise: you'll have to benchmark it with small and big sets. An `OrderBy` should be `O(nlogn)`, but an ordering by `true`/`false` (as in this case) is probably more similar to `O(n)`

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your answer. Why "OrderBy doesn't preserve order of the elements"? This is getting even more confusing with the next clause "the resulting ordered elements are ordered only...".

Comment: @TimSchmelter It means I was stupid and I was writing stupid things. It happens :-)

Comment: Never mind, could have been that i didn't get it. However, the `ThenBy` is needed if OP wants to split first by those which start with `f` and then by alphabetic sorting. Otherwise you only get the two groups, starting with `f` and not starting with `f` but both groups completely  unsorted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't see any alphabetic sorting in his example... I think `.ThenBy(a => a)` was to force a stable sorting of the other elements. And in the example 1 there wasn't any sorting.

Comment: @xanatosd: you're right, applied if it was `ThenBy(a => a.Code)`.

Comment: I would like to place the startswith at the bottom of the list. and The rest doesnt need to be sorted at all. it is like 2 groups one starts with f a the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The second example reads better.

Don't think you need the .ToList() after Distinct().

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use GroupBy and ToLookup to get the results that you are looking for.

```
        var allRoles = roles.Table
            .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new FirmRole
            {
                Code = p.Field<string>("RoleName"),
                Name = p.Field<string>("RoleName")
            }).GroupBy(x => x.StartsWith("f")).ToLookup(g => g.Key);;

        var formRoles = allRoles[true].ToList();
        var otherRoles = allRoles[false].ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can implement a custom sort comparison class based on the `IComparer<T>` interface for providing the required custom sorting:

```
public class CustomSortComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            StringComparer sc = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
            {
                return sc.Compare(x, y);
            }

            if (x.StartsWith("f", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && 
                !y.StartsWith("f", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (y.StartsWith("f", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && 
                !x.StartsWith("f", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return sc.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }
```

And then call:

```
var allRoles = roles.Table
      .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new FirmRole
      {
          Code = p.Field<string>("RoleName"),
          Name = p.Field<string>("RoleName")
      }).OrderBy(x => x.Code, new CustomSortComparer()).ToList();
```